# How to read i-result set and skip others in QueryMultiple

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

is it possible to skip result sets in QueryMultiple and get just i-result set?

Let's say we have 3 (or more!) result sets

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID; SELECT * FROM InvoiceItem WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID; SELECT * FROM InvoiceConfiguration WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;";

using (var connection = My.ConnectionFactory())
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {InvoiceID = 1}))
    {
        var invoice = multi.Read<Invoice>().First();
    
        //I don't need the second result set, only 1 and 3
        var unused = multi.Read<InvoiceItem>().ToList();

        var invoiceConfiguration = multi.Read<InvoiceConfiguration>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you don't need the second result set, then why not just remove that SQL from the query? Maybe dynamically concatenate the queries you _do_ want?

Comment: @D Stanley There are many different ways how to get results I need including to remove sets or create a different sproc, but I was asking is it possible to iterate thru the result sets and use one or another when needed, thank you anyway for your respond

Answer (score 1):

There is a method on `GridReader` (the result of `QueryMultiple`) called [`NextResult`](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/ca00feeb5fafe5262166689c0bec2b80b53add4e/Dapper/SqlMapper.GridReader.cs#L385) which in turn moves the `IDataReader` forward to the next resultset, but unfortunately it's `private`. It might be worth putting in a feature request for it.

You could instead just dispose the enumerator immediately

```cs
multi.Read<InvoiceItem>(buffered: false).Dispose();
```

This does have the downside of reading at least one row though, but that's unlikely to make much difference.

Or for async you can do this

```cs
(await multi.ReadAsync<InvoiceItem>(buffered: false)).Dispose();
```

You can even create extension functions for these

```cs
public void NextResult(this SqlMapper.GridReader reader) =>
    multi.Read<dynamic>(buffered: false).Dispose();

public async Task NextResultAsync(this SqlMapper.GridReader reader) =>
    (await multi.ReadAsync<dynamic>(buffered: false)).Dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, your solution is better then mine: 

            //var unused4 = await gridReaderProject.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            gridReaderProject.ReadAsync().Dispose();
        
I need to skip 4 result sets to get the last one I need.... definitely to have NextResult or to have sets as a collection would be useful

Comment: You want to `await` the async result, see edit

Comment: Your example is not making much sense to me. `Read<T>` returns `IEnumerable`, which doesn't implement `IDisposable`. Am I missing something obvious here? Also, both your proposed extensions should use `reader`, not `multi´ correct?